# SQL 2 statements creating a 3 statement, and joining the 2 together

Tags: sql-server, select, join

This is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT repnr, DATEDIFF(day, MIN(start), MAX(start) +1) AS DaysTotal
FROM TBLstatus 
WHERE status IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 11, 20, 7, 23)
GROUP BY repnr HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 AND MAX(Start) > GETDATE()-30

Select repnr as repnr, CONVERT(float, SUM(DATEDIFF(day, start, slut))) as extern
From TBLstatus 
where status IN (5, 15, 17)
group by repnr
```

The first will return this data:

```
repnr daystotal
1000  100
1001  90
1003  91
```

and the second statement:

```
repnr extern
900   100
901   102
1000  21
1003  23
```

What i want is that where the repnr (which is an ID) matches, i want to minus the to values so i would look like this:

```
repnr result
1000  79
1003  68
```

How do i do this for a MSSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT q1.repnr, q1.daystotal - q2.extern as [result]
FROM
(
SELECT repnr, DATEDIFF(day, MIN(start), MAX(start) +1) AS DaysTotal
FROM TBLstatus 
WHERE status IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 11, 20, 7, 23)
GROUP BY repnr HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 AND MAX(Start) > GETDATE()-30
)q1
INNER JOIN 
(
Select repnr as repnr, CONVERT(float, SUM(DATEDIFF(day, start, slut))) as extern
From TBLstatus 
where status IN (5, 15, 17)
group by repnr
)q2 ON q1.repnr = q2.repnr
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your queries as subqueries and join on your key and you should be good to go.

```
select repnr, DaysTotal - extern as result from (SELECT repnr, DATEDIFF(day, MIN(start), MAX(start) +1) AS DaysTotal
FROM TBLstatus 
WHERE status IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 11, 20, 7, 23)
GROUP BY repnr HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 AND MAX(Start) > GETDATE()-30) a inner join (Select repnr as repnr, CONVERT(float, SUM(DATEDIFF(day, start, slut))) as extern
From TBLstatus 
where status IN (5, 15, 17)
group by repnr) b on a.repnr = b.repnr
```

Comment: @Mathias May I ask why you unaccepted my answer and where's the difference between this answer and mine?

Comment: This one seems better, and shorter, the select statements are merged together.

Comment: @Mathias The queries are exactly the same! He just removed the line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.repnr, ABS(A.daystotal - b.extern) AS result
FROM(
SELECT repnr, DATEDIFF(day, MIN(start), MAX(start) +1) AS DaysTotal
FROM TBLstatus 
WHERE status IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 11, 20, 7, 23)
GROUP BY repnr HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 AND MAX(Start) > GETDATE()-30
)A
JOIN(
Select repnr as repnr, CONVERT(float, SUM(DATEDIFF(day, start, slut))) as extern
From TBLstatus 
where status IN (5, 15, 17)
group by repnr
)B
ON A.repnr = b.repnr
```